# Is it a good practice to have "Query fields" in objects?

Tags: java, oop

Imagine this example: there are a `Set<Loan> loans` in one of my classes, the purpose of this Set is to save the Loan history of a user in this system (bank system for example), if this Set is empty, it indicates that this user doesn't have any Loan, here is my question : 
is it a good practice to have a separate Boolean field, like `Boolean hasLoan;` for each user that shows the loan status of the user? I mean instead of checking for the emptiness of `Set<Loan> loans` i check the Boolean field for being true (has loan) and false (doesn't have).

same story about the number of loans: instead of calling  `loan.length` , I provide a field, like `int loanCount` and read its value?

by the way, I update these fields (`hasLoan` and  `loanCount` )  every time that a loan added or removed. I call these fields "query fields" because I use them to answer the queries about the main Collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to have a private member `Boolean hasLoan`; You can just make a getter:

```
public boolean hasLoan() {
    return !loans.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: yeah, but the question is which one has less overhead than the other? or which costs less

Comment: The difference is so small, that it is not important. Don't optimize prematurely. To be honest: the `private boolean` variable maybe will be nanoseconds faster than using everytime the `!loans.isEmpty()`, but it is less clear. And the clearness is most important, when the performance difference is negligble.

Comment: are you considering database fetching? this set may become too large in the future :-?

Comment: Yep cleanliness is king, in the end you will put alot of effort into refactoring/rewriting/extending code and then it will pay off

Comment: I don't get the problem. `!loans.isEmpty()` doesn't care about how large is the list. It is blazingly fast, because it only cares if there is at least one element in the list.

Comment: @peter hmmm, is it also true about the list count?

Comment: i agree that cleanliness is king, but when you use Hibernate, fetching that Set into memory is too costly, even using sizeOf method is fetching the  entire set into memory

Comment: @dave - Yes, I am sure the `HashSet` uses its own internal mechanisms with a counter - just like yours. It doesn't iterate through the whole set. You are just duplicating functionality.

Comment: @dave - Hibernate is another thing - you haven't mentioned it in your question. If you want only the count, but not the entities in the memory, make a query for it.

Answer (score 2):

Data isolation is a core tenet of OO design. One aspect is that you should always avoid duplicating the same data in more than one place. The determining factor when deciding to break this isolation should be if the act of re-calculating the value has a significant performance impact on the overall system.

Calling `isEmpty()` or `size()` on a standard java Collection implementation is of negligible cost so you should not duplicate the results of those properties.

The reason for this is code robustness and maintainability. 99 times out of 100, performance optimization WILL reduce code maintainability as it will introduce added complexity like caching, non-intuitive code paths and anti-patterns, breaking OO design and isolation. Sub-optimization is the bane and nemesis of maintainable code and design and should always be avoided. Never optimize for the sake of optimizing, optimize where it's worth it, where it delivers a significant performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

Each update to the loan Set should lead to an update of the boolean field which is a side effect of the method. Non-obvious [side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) should be avoided.

Furthermore, it leads to information redundancy which in turn leads to a higher probability of making a mistake when changing the class or not to update the field in a derived type.
This is even more valid if you are working in a team, where you would have to explain the inner workings of a class to every person not familiar with it in order to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the list, it is better to have the boolean variable.
This is because, for everytime you will have to fetch the list data from the database, 
then find the length of the list. 
Surely, using the boolean variable will save the extra step.

Additionally, make sure that there aer no addiditonal sources for database updates.
Lest it may leave the hasLoan variable not updated.

Comment: What extra step? When you fetch the data, you have to populate again the `boolean` variable.

Comment: The extra step is finding the count of the list, which is worth a line of code.